# ORMLite android updatebuilder

Tags: android, ormlite

Can any one help me out to update an entire object with a where condition in ormlite. I know its possible to update a column using where condition but i need to update the full row with one column value in where condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[createOrUpdate](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#createOrUpdate%28T%29) method does the same.*

---

From doc it says that

***createOrUpdate(T data)***

> This is a convenience method for creating an item in the database if
>   it does not exist. The id is extracted from the data argument and a
>   query-by-id is made on the database. If a row in the database with the
>   same id exists then all of the columns in the database will be updated
>   from the fields in the data parameter. If the id is null (or 0 or some
>   other default value) or doesn’t exist in the database then the object
>   will be created in the database. This also means that your data item
>   must have an id field defined.